# Finding a simple shape within a 3D point cloud

Tags: algorithm, graph, 3d, point

What is the most efficient way to find a shape that is defined by 5 rigid, coplanar, non-collinear points within a point cloud of, for example, 100 3D points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a simple template within a 3D point cloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181107/finding-a-simple-template-within-a-3d-point-cloud)

Comment: The last one was closed before anyone could answer; I've made this one to clear up the question.

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me. Possibly homework though.

Comment: Asking the same question again is frowned upon here on Stack Overflow. It would have been better to edit the previous question. I don't know why people closed the previous question, but I think they wanted to see more research effort. Meanwhile, welcome on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Take a look on [Hough trasform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). Probably it isn't most efficient, but at least works in theory :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that distances are invariant under the relevant transformations (rotation, shift, etc). So it would be a good idea to match distances. Try this:

First, create a data-structure with all pairwise distances for the 3d cloud. That's 100x100 so it isn't too bad.

Now, just start matching distances: For each point in the 2d set, see if there is a matching distance in the 3d set. Maintain a graph of matching distances and slowly expand it.

Do you see how to make this into an algorithm? With the correct data-structures this could be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

### Brute force approach

In pseudo code:

```
Find all possible three point tuples from your set of points.
Every three-tuple now defines a plane.
For all planes:
   filter the set of points for points that lie in the plane
   if you have five or more points remaining, return the first five and exit  
return NOT_FOUND and exit
```

Note that the complexity of this approach is **Factorial** that means **O(n!)**

For example, for a set of one hundred points, you'll have to do ~17 million coplanarity checks, and for a thousand points, ~170 billion coplanarity checks.

Comment: Would this work if the shape in the 3D point cloud is distorted by noise?

Comment: If the noise is linear within the plane, sure. But not if you have random noise. If you have random noise, you'll have to describe each points as spheres (radius ∝ noise) and find five spheres that intersect a single plane. This will be quite a bit harder and more expensive.

Comment: @jellybean What's the use case?

Answer (score -1):

You can select 5 points and find a shape. 100C5 will do the trick. Now how to compute the combinations efficiently you can find algorithms for it.  A sample implementation is available [here](http://blog.abhinavmathur.net/2013/06/algorithm-to-compute-combinations.html)

Comment: I don't think this will do, as they have to be coplanar.

Comment: may be we can compute combinations and then see which one of them give us 5 co-planar points and then consider those combinations only to get shape